# Править или не править?

Tags: обсуждение, дефект, предлагаемые-правки, правки

На странице правки сообщения можно увидеть следующий текст:

> Ваша правка будет поставлена в очередь, пока не пройдёт экспертную
> проверку.
>
> Мы рады любым конструктивным правкам, но они должны быть
> **существенными**. Вносить несущественные правки разрешается только в
> случаях крайней необходимости.

В то же время, справа можно увидеть "Руководство по редактированию":

> ► **исправьте грамматические или орфографические ошибки**
>
> ► уточните смысл, не изменяя его
>
> ► исправьте **незначительные** ошибки
>
> ► добавьте связанные ресурсы или ссылки
>
> ► всегда проявляйте уважение к автору

В первом источнике говорится, что правки должны быть существенными, во втором - можно править грамматические, орфографические и *несущественные* ошибки. Противоречие. Кому верить?

P.S. Поставил метку *дефект*, т.к. по-сути противоречивую информацию можно считать дефектом сайта.

#### UPD

> Не стоит затевать проверяемую правку только ради исправления
> несущественной ошибки. Но в прочих случаях их, конечно, надо править.
> – Nofate♦

Теперь понятно, что не было никакого противоречия. Но, в таком случае, стоит перефразировать первый текст. Формулировка @Nofate гораздо более прозрачна.

Comment: Не стоит затевать проверяемую правку *только* ради исправления несущественной ошибки. Но в прочих случаях их, конечно, надо править.

Comment: Очень актуальный вопрос, верно подмечены противоречия.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Важно разделять **предлагаемые правки** и **непроверяемые правки**.

- **Предлагаемые** совершаются в вопросы и ответы при уровне репутации < 2 000 и в описания меток при репутации < 20 000. Эти правки применяются только после того, как их одобрят другие участники в специальной очереди проверок.
- **Непроверяемые** совершаются при превышении вышеописанных порогов репутации для соответствующих текстов, и применяются немедленно, без рассмотрения.

"Что исправлять" актуально всегда. Руководство по редактированию действует для правок всех видов, для любых текстов и при любом уровне репутации.

А требование "существенности" относится только к *предлагаемым* правкам, это дополнительное требование, **не *вместо*** "что исправлять", **а *вместе***. Это мягкое дополнительное ограничение на минимальный объём того, "что исправлять" правкой. Никакого противоречия. Если вы не нашли достаточно проблем в сообщении, которые можете поправить, оставьте как есть.

В сущности, это убедительная просьба не расходовать ресурс очереди проверок для правок по мелочам. Заработав 2 000 репутации, можно спокойно заняться и несущественными правками тоже, ведь очередь уже не будет участвовать в процессе.

---

Можно уточнить формулировку, явно указав на "предлагаемость" следующим образом:

> любым конструктивным правкам => предложению любых конструктивных правок
>   Вносить => Предлагать