# Правила изменения заголовка вопроса

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, правки

Я только начал заниматься правкой чужих вопросов, и вот возникла сложность. Некоторые пользователи могут писать заголовок своего вопроса с маленькой буквы, или сам вопрос начинается с маленькой буквы. С одной стороны из-за замены маленькой буквы на большую ничего не меняется в вопросе, но с другой стороны красивее и приятнее читать правильно оформленный вопрос. Просто когда идет проверка моей правки, то не всегда проверяющий считает что моя правка имеет влияние на вопрос. Надеюсь что вы поможете в моей сложной ситуации.

Связанные обсуждения:

1. [Править или не править?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6800/15479)
2. [Незначительные правки](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1951/15479).
3. [Косметические правки. "вы → Вы", "е → ё"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3668/15479).